# Magento 2.2.10 + Porto Theme after install theme, HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento2

[16-Jun-2020 01:01:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addCategoryFilter() on null in /home/vip/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php:57
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vip/public_html/generated/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList/Interceptor.php(24): Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList->getProducts()
#1 /home/vip/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php(33): Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList\Interceptor->getProducts()
#2 /home/vip/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(187): Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList->_getProductCollection()
#3 /home/vip/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(666): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_beforeToHtml()
#4 /home/vip/public_html/generated/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList/Interceptor.php(908): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#5 /home/vip/public_html/vendor/magento/module in /home/vip/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php on line 57

Answer (score 0):

Take the backup of your file

> /app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php

And replace the file with the below code and check

```
<?php

namespace Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class LatestList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

    protected $_collection;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        $count = $this->getProductCount();
        $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
        $collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        if(!$category_id) {
            $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        }
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category_id);
        if(isset($category) && $category) {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite() 
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        } else {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        }

        $collection->getSelect()
                ->order('created_at','desc')
                ->limit($count);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }

    public function getProductCount() {
        $limit = $this->getData("product_count");
        if(!$limit)
            $limit = 10;
        return $limit;
    }
}
```

I hope it will work for you.